# Regular Expression for removing suffix

Tags: c++, regex, qt4

What is the regular expression for removing the suffix of file names? For example, if I have a file name in a string such as "vnb.txt", what is the regular expression to remove ".txt"?
Thanks.

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++ or qt4?

Comment: @John Dibling: I would guess it's because the OP is also using Qt4 and C++. If there were a solution specific to Qt4/C++, I imagine that it would probably be very welcome over a generic solution.

Comment: How do you know a bit after a . is really a suffix?  ".hidenfile" What about multiple suffix? "foo.bar.tar.gz"  What is the end aim of manipulating the filename?

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need a regular expression to do this? Why not just look for the last period in the string, and trim the string up to that point? Frankly, there's a lot of overhead for a regular expression, and I don't think you need it in this case.

As suggested by tstenner, you can try one of the following, depending on what kinds of strings you're using:

[std::strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strrchr/)

[std::string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)

First example:

```
char* str = "Directory/file.txt";

size_t index;
char* pStr = strrchr(str,'.');
if(nullptr != pStr)
{
    index = pStr - str;
}
```

Second example:

```
int index = string("Directory/file.txt").find_last_of('.');
```

Comment: True for filenames, but not true for pathnames.

Comment: You might want to add a reference to string::find_last_of.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Qt already, you could use [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html), and use the [baseName()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html#baseName) function to get just the name (if one exists), or the [suffix()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html#suffix) function to get the extension (if one exists).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a solution that will give you anything except for the suffix, you should use [string::find_last_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/).

Your code could look like this:

```
const std::string removesuffix(const std::string& s) {
  size_t suffixbegin = s.find_last_of('.');

  //This will handle cases like "directory.foo/bar"
  size_t dir = s.find_last_of('/');
  if(dir != std::string::npos && dir > suffixbegin) return s;
  if(suffixbegin == std::string::npos) return s;
  else return s.substr(0,suffixbegin);
}
```

If you're looking for a regular expression, use `\.[^.]+$`.
You have to escape the first `.`, otherwise it will match any character, and put a $ at the end, so it will only match at the end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Different operating systems may allow different characters in filenams, the simplest regex might be `(.+)\.txt$`. Get the first capture group to get the filename sans extension.

Comment: To match any filename extension, not just `.txt`, use `(.+)\.([^\.]+)` (and if this doesn't match, then the filename has no extension.)

Comment: @Felix Dombek: You also need to be able to handle filenames such as `ENV1.20110329.dat`... I think your pattern would capture `ENV1` and `20110329` but would not get the file extension `.dat`.

Comment: no, not if the first capture group is not specified as reluctant (`(\.+?)`). But if you want to be absolutely sure, you can of course use `^` and `$`: the complete regex is then `^(.+)\.([^\.]+)$`